# I want to fill the voxilized Volume [VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh] open3d

Tags: python, optimization, 3d, mesh, open3d

I'm trying to voxelize an **.obj** mesh and convert it to a **numpy array** (**save it as a .npy** or nii.gz as a CT-3D image).

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('path/to/file.obj')
voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(mesh, voxel_size=0.01)
voxels = np.array([voxel.grid_index for voxel in voxel_grid.get_voxels()])
```

The problem is that the voxel_array bellow is **hollow (I see just the surface)**

```
grid_size = voxels.max(axis=0) + 1

voxel_array = np.zeros(grid_size, dtype=np.uint16)
voxel_array[voxels[:, 0], voxels[:, 1], voxels[:, 2]] = 1

np.save('path/to/file_open3d.npy', voxel_array)
```

I haven't found a way to fill without using loops on voxel_array !
I'm looking for a way to do it with **open3d** to benefit from the **CUDA** advantage.